# Logging $_SERVER to mysql

Tags: php

I use this code , to log  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  to my small db 
my issue is value never saved to db , cant figure what i missed in the code

Any tips ?

```
 <?php

 mysql_connect("localhost", "usr", "passwd");
 mysql_select_db("db") or die ( 'Can not select database' );

 function initCounter() {
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO logs(REMOTE_ADDR,) VALUES ('$ip')";
  }
   echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

   ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide the schema for your `logs` table? Also, you have a trailing comma in the column list of your `INSERT` statement, and you are not executing that statement anywhere. Is this the actual code?

Comment: Should he try that query directly against the db, i think it would fail ;)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logs` (
  `REMOTE_ADDR` int(250) NOT NULL,
  KEY `REMOTE_ADDR` (`REMOTE_ADDR`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: `REMOTE_ADDR,` <-- That trailing comma won't be doing you any favors. Also, You never call `mysql_query()` anywhere...

Comment: You never execute the query. Also please avoid using mysql_* function, they are in deprecation process. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: i called mysql_query($sql); after

Comment: still nothing fetched to db , set error on and nothing show as error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. In addition to the other comments here, you had a comma (,) too much in your query.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "usr", "passwd");
mysql_select_db("db") or die ( 'Can not select database' );

function initCounter() {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO logs (REMOTE_ADDR) VALUES ('$ip')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}

initCounter();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You aren't actually executing the query. You create the SQL but don't use `mysql_query($sql)`
- You have a comma at this point in the SQL `REMOTE_ADDR,` <-- remove that
- When you execute the query, use `mysql_error()` to test for an error message (and check the result of `mysql_query()` for a boolean `false`.

Finally I would suggest switching to MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

If that's you're full code... there is one thing missing *you actually need to EXECUTE the query*...

mysql_query($sql);

EDIT:

I have just noticed, you're connecting to the DB *OUTSIDE* of the function trying to run the Query... obviously it will fail as inside the function, it has no awareness of the DB connection.

Comment: @Brian the function does have db access, `mysql_query()` is not affected by function scope here because `mysql_query()` uses the last opened connection if the `$link` argument is omitted.